# Template class that has all virtual functions inline

Tags: c++, templates, gdb, inline, member

I'm using class templates which contain virtual functions in my current project, and I stumbled upon a problem I can't overcome on my own.

1. Class templates cannot have their member function bodies split from class
   definition in .hpp file because of linker errors. I don't want to
   instantiate my templates for each new type I'm abut to use, so all
   that's left is to leave them inlined. This is absolutely
   fine as they are 1-2 lines long most of the time, so I'm not going
   to experience any code bloat.
2. On the other hand, gcc creates vtable for a polymorphic class in
   .cpp file that has definition of the first non-inline function that
   is declared in the class definition. Since I have all member
   functions inline, I'm getting undefined reference to vtable, or no
   RTTI symbol found for my class in GDB.

Please consider the following code:

```
template <typename T>
struct Test
{
    virtual void testMe() const = 0;
    virtual ~Test() = default;
};

template <typename T>
struct test : public Test<T>
{
    virtual void testMe() const
    {
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~test() = default;
};

int main()
{
    test<int> t;
    Test<int>& T = t;

    T.testMe();

    return 0;
}
```

In this particular example I'm getting:

```
can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `test<int>' value
```

when debugging with GDB.

How do I force my compiler to put vtable in a specific cpp file when all class functions are inline?

---

**EDIT**:

Since the example provided above didn't illustrate the problem, here's my original code.

The class that's causing the problem:

```
#ifndef CONVERTIBLETO_H
#define CONVERTIBLETO_H

#include "convertibleTo_converters.h"
#include <functional>

template <
            typename IT,
            template <typename InterfaceType, typename ErasedType>
                class Converter = convertibleTo_detail::default_converter
         >
class convertibleTo
{
public:
    typedef convertibleTo<IT, Converter> this_type;
    typedef IT InterfaceType;

    struct is_type_eraser_tag {};
private:

    class holder_interface
    {
    public:
        virtual InterfaceType get() const = 0;
        virtual void set(const InterfaceType&) = 0;
        virtual holder_interface* clone() const = 0;

        virtual ~holder_interface() {}
    };


        template <typename ErasedType>
        class holder : public holder_interface
        {
        public:
            virtual InterfaceType get() const
            {
                return (Converter<InterfaceType, ErasedType>::convert(this->data));
            }
            virtual void set(const InterfaceType& value)
            {
                this->data = (Converter<InterfaceType, ErasedType>::convert(value));
            }
            virtual holder_interface* clone() const
            {
                return new holder(*this);
            }

            holder() = delete;
            holder(const holder& other):
                data(other.data)
            { }
            holder(ErasedType& d):
                data(d)
            { }

            virtual ~holder() = default;

        private:
            ErasedType& data;
        };
public:

    inline InterfaceType get() const
    {
        if (this->held)
            return this->held->get();
        else
            return InterfaceType();
    }

    inline void set(const InterfaceType& value)
    {
        if (this->held)
            this->held->set(value);
    }

    inline bool empty() const
    {
        return ! this->held;
    }

    convertibleTo<InterfaceType, Converter>& operator= (const convertibleTo<InterfaceType, Converter>& other)
    {
        if(this->held)
            delete this->held;
        this->held = other.held->clone();
        return *this;
    }

    convertibleTo():
        held(nullptr)
    { }

    template <typename T>
    explicit convertibleTo(T& data):
        held(new holder<T>(data))
    {
    }

    convertibleTo( convertibleTo& other ):
        convertibleTo( const_cast<const convertibleTo&>(other))
    {
    }

    convertibleTo( const convertibleTo& other ):
        held(nullptr)
    {
        if(other.held)
            this->held = other.held->clone();
    }

    ~convertibleTo()
    {
        if (this->held)
            delete this->held;
    }

private:
    holder_interface * held;
};

#endif
```

Required helper classes:

```
#ifndef CONVERTIBLETO_CONVERTERS_H
#define CONVERTIBLETO_CONVERTERS_H

#include <string>
#include <sstream>

namespace convertibleTo_detail
{
    template <typename InterfaceType, typename ErasedType>
    struct default_converter
    {
        static inline InterfaceType convert(const ErasedType& input)
        {
            return input;
        }

        static inline ErasedType convert(const InterfaceType& input)
        {
            return input;
        }
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct default_converter<T, T>
    {
        static inline T convert(const T& input)
        {
            return input;
        }
    };

    template <typename ErasedType>
    struct default_converter<std::string, ErasedType>
    {
        static inline std::string convert(const ErasedType& input)
        {
            default_converter<std::string, ErasedType>::prepareConverter();
            default_converter<std::string, ErasedType>::converter << input;
            return default_converter<std::string, ErasedType>::converter.str();
        }

        static inline ErasedType convert(const std::string& input)
        {
            default_converter<std::string, ErasedType>::prepareConverter(input);
            ErasedType result;
            default_converter<std::string, ErasedType>::converter >> result;

            return result;
        }

    private:

        static std::stringstream converter;

        struct SetExceptionFlagsOnce      
        {
            SetExceptionFlagsOnce()
            {
                default_converter<std::string, ErasedType>::converter.exceptions(std::stringstream::failbit);
            }
        };

        static void inline prepareConverter(std::string value = "")
        {
            static SetExceptionFlagsOnce setter;
            default_converter<std::string, ErasedType>::converter.clear();
            default_converter<std::string, ErasedType>::converter.str(value);
        }
    };

    template <typename ErasedType>
    std::stringstream default_converter<std::string, ErasedType>::converter;

    template <>
    struct default_converter<std::string, std::string>
    {
        static inline std::string convert(const std::string& input)
        {
            return input;
        }
    };
}

#endif // CONVERTIBLETO_CONVERTERS_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "convertibleTo.h"


int main()
{

    int I = 5;

    convertibleTo< std::string > i(I);

    std::cout << i.get() << std::endl;
    i.set("321");
    std::cout << i.get() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Error I'm getting is:

```
RTTI symbol not found for class 'convertibleTo<std::string, convertibleTo_detail::default_converter>::holder<int>'
```

it's shown when I go inside i.get(), and then inside holder's get().

---

**EDIT**: Moved the full source from pastebin here, as per suggestion

---

Since the last two comments suggested that this is a GDB bug, how do I check this myself next time?

1. In case GDB complains about missing vtable - would confirming that I can access every virtual member through a reference to ABC initialized with derived class be enough to confirm that everything is OK?
2. In case GDB complains about missing RTTI symbol - would calling typeid() on the reference to ABC initialized with derived class to be enough to confirm that the RTTI symbol is, in fact, present?

Comment: Is that the only message about missing symbols you get from GDB?

Comment: Usually it works to provide inline code definitions for template (or regular) classes, the compiler should sort them out not to be inlined at linkage level!

Comment: http://ideone.com/zy4rN1 works fine for me.

Comment: Now this is strange. I didn't comment out a piece of code from my project that was causing the mentioned problem, and I got this GDB warning abut test class provided in OP. Is this cross-class vtable interaction even possible? Should I post the original class that's causing the problem? It's ~150 lines long.

Comment: If you're going to refer in GDB, shouldn't that s.th. like `test<int>` actually? I'm not sure though ...

Comment: you can add  original code using paste.bin or similar sites

Comment: the original code is in the OP.

Comment: I did not find any Rtti(typeid) in your classes.If you are getting warnings just ignore on this case. Plus note that external link (paste.bin) should always work. Otherwise,You can get downvotes. mostly using paste.bin in stackoverflow is discouraged.So after getting your answer edit your question that will hold real problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unkwnown source of warning: "can't find linker symbol for virtual table for..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721648/unkwnown-source-of-warning-cant-find-linker-symbol-for-virtual-table-for) (it's a GDB bug, no problem with your code)

Comment: Since this is the core feature of my application I have to be absolutely sure that this is a GDB bug and not my code's fault. To confirm:
- If I can access all of the derived class' methods through reference to pure virtual base class, it means that vtable was created correctly. 
- If I can get a typeid of derived class from reference to pure virtual base class, it means that RTTI symbol was created correctly. 

Are the above statements true, and is manual testing the correct way to confirm that my code is correct despite what GDB says?

Comment: I just debugged you code stepping through every line of code using GDB without any complaints. I am using a pretty old version of GCC (Debian stable) g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2.

Comment: Actually, you can perfectly automate testing. Using `nm`, for example, you can list the symbols present in library; and thus you can verify that the symbols corresponding to the virtual table of a class are present (`nm yourlib | grep yourclass`)

Comment: I was able to execute the above code using gcc 4.6.1 specifying the -std=c++0x flag with only one change: removing the virtual tag for the deconstructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code (the full version, with two header files and main.C) compiles and links without any errors for me, with gcc 4.8.3, with the default options (except for -std=c++11, to enable C++11 mode).

I even loaded the resulting executable into gdb. gdb swallowed it without any issues.

I don't see anything wrong here.